# From matrix to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I try to create a 2D array,
I followed the next steps,
but I couldn't create a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array([(1,0), (0.33,0.67)])
```

but I get the following error

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-4851c8fca996> in <module>()
----> 1 print(b)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in array_str(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small)
   1959 
   1960     """
-> 1961     return array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, ' ', "", str)
   1962 
   1963 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py in array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, separator, prefix, style, formatter)
    461     else:
    462         lst = _array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small,
--> 463                             separator, prefix, formatter=formatter)
    464     return lst
    465 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py in _array2string(a, max_line_width, precision, suppress_small, separator, prefix, formatter)
    321     else:
    322         summary_insert = ""
--> 323         data = ravel(asarray(a))
    324 
    325     # find the right formatting function for the array

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in ravel(a, order)
   1463 
   1464     """
-> 1465     if isinstance(a, np.matrix):
   1466         return asarray(a).ravel(order=order)
   1467     else:

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Any type of help would be great.
​

Comment: I ran your code. It works fine. Can you exit the terminal and re run the code? It should work fine

Comment: works for me as well, which version of python are you using?

Comment: The two lines of code run just fine. More information on the context is needed but this might be anything like a numpy installation error, for instance. Can you give the Python version, the method you used to install NumPy and the way with which you run the code (the Python command-line, a program file, IPython, etc) ?

Comment: Did you forget to type the `[` and `]`?

Comment: The version of Python is 3.5.

Comment: The error indicates that `np.matrix` has been overriden in some way. Have you restarted the IPython console/notebook as suggested by Clock Slave? Are you running these commands after some initialization code that is not shown here?

Comment: It was a problem with the IPython environment. When I restart Jupyter I was able to create my numpy array